# How to preserve localStorage data after page redirect?

Tags: javascript, thread-local-storage

I'm facing strange behavior with localStorage. I'm wanting to set data then redirect user to the dashboard if localStorage data is set. If I set localStorage data, refresh page and stay on the same page, localStorage is preserved. However, if I redirect user to a different page localStorage is destroyed. How can I make this work?

**This works and preserves data**

```
var session = 'true';
localStorage.setItem("session", session);
//refresh page 
location.reload();
```

**This destroys data**

```
var session = 'true';
localStorage.setItem("session", session);
//redirect user
location.href="user/dashboard.html";
```

**user/session.js**

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {


    //no session found
    if(localStorage.getItem("session")===null){

        //redirect user to main page 
        location.href="../login.html";


    }else{

    //perform session queries below

    }

});
```

Comment: have you checked in the browser console if `session` exist in `localStorage`?

Comment: @JamalAbo: It prints true before page redirect. user/session.js returns null every single time.

Comment: so `session` exists in the browser console, which means that the code fails to obtain the `session` content or check it ?!

Comment: have you checked this in another browser? (btw what browser are you using?)

Comment: @JamalAbo: right now debugging with Firefox.

Comment: Change session.js so it doesn't do the redirect, but instead does `console.log(localStorage.getItem("session"));` - see what it says.

Comment: @Archer : It returns null.